# On submit form Display data into table using echo in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

**I have a table, displayied with an echo, where, for each row I'd like to have a button to change a "status" field (I want to update just one field). I am trying to insert a form button into my echo but I don't get anything.**

This is my echo code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['fullname'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['message'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['country'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['website'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . " </td>";

        echo "<form action='updatestatus.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row['id']."' name='id' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row['status']."' name='status' />";
            echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></td>";
        echo "</form>";

        echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

> updatestatus.php

```
// check if the form has been submitted. 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
    if (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
        // get form data, making sure it is valid
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];

        if ($status == 0) {
            $status == 1;
            mysql_query("UPDATE personalguestbook SET status='$status' WHERE id='$id'")
            or die(mysql_error());
        } else {
            $status == 0;
            mysql_query("UPDATE personalguestbook SET status='$status' WHERE id='$id'")
            or die(mysql_error()); 
        }
        header("Location: view.php"); 
    }
}
```

So, if my status field is = 0, I want to change it = 1 and update into my database, and vice versa.

Thanks for your attention

Comment: "I am trying to insert a form button into my echo but I don't get anything." -> do you mean the button doesn't appear? **BTW**, "$_POST['id']" isn't defined - you should add an hidden input with the row's id as a value.

Comment: What doesn't working ? Status doesn't change ?

Comment: First of all, this wont work. Your buttons have to have unique names, otherwise PHP wont know which one you pressed. Second point: You're trying to check `$_POST` variables, altough you're not submitting anyone. Your form has only a submit button. There won't be a `$_POST[id]` for example. Last point: Look at http://bobby-tables.com and read a bit about sql injection. You're using mysql_* which is deprecated. Use mysqli_* or PDO_* instead. Also look at what prepared statements are. The way your code is written now, your database can be hacked in 5 seconds, nearly without any knowhow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my code but it still doesn't work. Any suggestion please?

Comment: "*...I don't get anything...*" like I don't understand anything? Please be specific when describing a problem. What exactly do you expect to happen and what exactly happens instead.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean my value doen't change and that field in my database is not updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form isn't sending anything to updatestatus.php, you can add the data to POST in a hidden form like so:

```
echo "<form action='updatestatus.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row['id']."' name='id' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row['status']."' name='status' />";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></td>";
echo "</form>";
```

This is the simple fix to your code above, there are still some security flaws and efficiency methods others have mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working Ps. You should chnage this "" in hidden, id and status in ''. because I got an error there e.g. 'hidden', 'id', 'status'

Comment: @James69 - Thanks, fixed!

Comment: You're welcome! It still doesn't work... Could be a mysql code error? Thanks

Comment: Added echo's to updatestatus.php to debug what values are coming through?

Comment: I tried to put an echo into updatestatus.php and I get just the current value, but there is no change about this value

Answer (score 0):

### Check this PHP code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['fullname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['message'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['country'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['website'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . " </td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<form action='updatestatus.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row['id']."' name='id' />";
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row['status']."' name='status' />";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></td>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 

}
```

> updatestatus.php

```
 // check if the form has been submitted. 
     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     { 
     // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
     if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
     {
     // get form data, making sure it is valid
     $id = $_POST['id'];

     $status = $_POST['status'];

     if ($status == 0){
         $status == 1;
         mysql_query("UPDATE personalguestbook SET status='".$status."' WHERE id='".$id."'")
     or die(mysql_error());
     } else {
          $status == 0;
         mysql_query("UPDATE personalguestbook SET status='".$status."' WHERE id='$id'")
     or die(mysql_error());

     }
       header("Location: view.php"); 
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working... Maybe the problem is in my mysql code... What do you think about it? Thanks

Comment: check $row by print_r($row);

Comment: sorry but I don't understand

Comment: If your table drawn incorrectly then please check my "updatestatus.php" code .. check it

Comment: Please check while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {  echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); }